# 2 same elements on page, how to click second one using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, element, webdriver, watir-webdriver

There are 2 images on a page that have the same image src link. If i use the following code it will click the first image, so how do I click on the second image?

```
browser.image(:src, "https://itc.mzstatic.com/itc/images/btn-grey-small-edit.png").click
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to either capture all images, and click the second one

```
browser.images(:src, "https://itc.mzstatic.com/itc/images/btn-grey-small-edit.png")[1].click
```

or specify the index of the image (index starts at 0 for watir-webdriver, or 1 for watir):

```
browser.image(:src => "https://itc.mzstatic.com/itc/images/btn-grey-small-edit.png", :index => 1).click
```

Comment: Know offhand what if I need to use the last matching element, not first, whatever index # it has? (i.e. when I don't know the number of matching elements in advance)